# Change resolution of one DataArray to match another

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have two DataArrays to merge into one DataSet for subsequent analyses.

The DataArrays have same extension but different resolution.
How can I change the resolution of the first DataArray to match the resolution of the second DataArray (e.g. using bilinear interpolation or nearest neighbour)?

Here is a reprex:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data1 = np.random.random((37, 33, 8))
da1 = xr.DataArray(data1, dims = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'], name='foo1')

data2 = np.random.random((41, 48, 8))
da2 = xr.DataArray(data2, dims = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'], name='foo2')

# SOME OPERATIONS HERE

ds = xr.merge([da1, da2])
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a very useful example in the xarray documentation (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html) which shows this is possible using interp() like so

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data1 = np.random.random((37, 33, 8))
da1 = xr.DataArray(data1, dims = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'], name='foo1')

data2 = np.random.random((41, 48, 8))
da2 = xr.DataArray(data2, dims = ['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'], name='foo2')

# Interpolate da1 to match da2 resolution
new_lon = np.linspace(da1.longitude[0], da1.longitude[-1], da2.sizes['longitude'])
new_lat = np.linspace(da1.latitude[0], da1.latitude[-1], da2.sizes['latitude'])
da1_interpolated = da1.interp(latitude = new_lat, longitude = new_lon)
da1_interpolated

# Merge DataArrays into DataSet
ds = xr.merge([da1_interpolated, da2])
```